# Decoding hex-encoded line in XeLaTeX

Tags: macros, xetex

I will try to adapt `pax.sty` for XeLaTeX and found that url in `.pax` files are encoded as hex line:

```
\[{annot}{1}{Link}{56.693 693.9 156.107 707.7}{URI}{
  URI={\<6D61696C746F3A68656C6C6F406578616D706C652E636F6D\>},
  Border={[0 0 0]},
}\\
```

Decoded URI is `mailto:hello@example.com` (can be seen by `xxd -r -p`)

How I can decode hex line in XeLaTeX (hex to ascii)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\hextotext}[1]{#1} % ???
\begin{document}
\hextotext{6D61696C746F3A68656C6C6F406578616D706C652E636F6D}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the url will be the hex coded utf-8 so presumably? you want the utf-8 defcoded character string not ascii, for xetext don't you?

Comment: I do have a local implementation which works with xelatex, but it relies on code we haven't released yet. If you want to try you can contact me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This hex encoded URL is a result of `pax` PDF annotation extractor (base on PDFBox java library). Maybe this form can be used directly in pdflatex..I not shure why it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\str_set_convert:Nnnn` to convert from (assuming) `utf8/hex` to `utf8`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l__ivanov_tmpa_str
\NewDocumentCommand \hextotext { o m }
  {
    \str_set_convert:Nxnn \l__ivanov_tmpa_str {#2}
      { utf8/hex } { utf8 }
    \IfValueTF{#1}
      { \str_set_eq:NN #1 \l__ivanov_tmpa_str }
      { \str_use:N \l__ivanov_tmpa_str }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set_convert:Nnnn { Nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\hextotext{6D61696C746F3A68656C6C6F406578616D706C652E636F6D}

\hextotext[\tmp]{6D61696C746F3A68656C6C6F406578616D706C652E636F6D}
\texttt{\meaning\tmp}

\end{document}
```

This prints:

> [image]

Comment: +1: Never expected that the code for this question can get so short and elegant.

Comment: Thank you very match! This solution can be used if argument is macros? Like `\def\a{6D6D} \hextotext{\a}`? I've try with `\expandafter` but without success.

Comment: @StanislavIvanov Well, I guess you won't have active characters in a hex string, so it probably won't harm to force an expansion there.  I changed the answer to expand everything, so `\hextotext{\a}` works

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

In the special case "hex to **ascii**" (as stated in your question) you can, e.g., lowercase the whole sequence, always insert `^^` before two successive characters of this sequence, and you have something that is interpreted, e.g., by `\scantokens` as the corresponding character sequence in `^^`-notation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\^^A=14\relax
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\@firstofone{^^A
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\hextotext[2]{^^A
    \@ifdefinable#1{^^A
      \lowercase{^^A
        \scantokens\expandafter{^^A
          \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter#1\expandafter{^^A
            \romannumeral\expandafter\hextotextloop\expandafter{\expandafter}\detokenize{#2}\relax\relax
          }%^^A
        }^^A
      }^^A
    }^^A
  }^^A
}%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\^=12\relax
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand*\hextotextloop[3]{%
    \ifx\relax#2\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\z@#1}{\hextotextloop{#1^^#2#3}}%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

%  6D61696C746F3A68656C6C6F406578616D706C652E636F6D

^^6d^^61^^69^^6c^^74^^6f^^3a^^68^^65^^6c^^6c^^6f^^40^^65^^78^^61^^6d^^70^^6c^^65^^2e^^63^^6f^^6d

\hextotext{\MyCommand}{6D61696C746F3A68656C6C6F406578616D706C652E636F6D}

\begingroup

\ttfamily

\string\MyCommand: \meaning\MyCommand

\endgroup

\MyCommand

\end{document}
```

[image]

**But this is for playing around only.**

**In real-life-scenarios I'd use [what is provided in Phelype Oleinik's answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569958/118714) That covers conversion of utf8/hex to utf8 while ASCII (what is covered in my answer) is just a subset of utf8.**

Comment: +1: How do you know that kind of stuff! :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  1) In the past and in the present I receive(d) great teaching in the usenet-newsgroups comp.text.tex and de.comp.text.tex and at TeX-LaTeX StackExchange.   2) Donald E. Knuth:  Computers & Typesetting, Volume A: The TeXbook